# violated frame-ancestors with asterisk value

Tags: html, http, content-security-policy

Today I ran into this weird console error in both chrome and safari:

Refused to display ... in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".

How is it even possible to violate *? Is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment really, but I've not got enough reputation. I've spent today trying to embed a Twitter timeline into a React-Native WebView. After getting the timeline to show I was faced with the videos not working. Hooking the WebView up to chrome devtools I found I had the same error as you.

In a React-Native webview you can pass the HTML to show and a 'baseUrl':

```
source={{
  html: '<html><body>Some stuff that generates a twitter timeline in an iframe</body></html>',
  baseUrl: ''
}}>
```

I had mine set to empty, as above, which I think creates a webview with the url '**about:blank**'. When I changed it to '**https://www.twitter.com**', the frame-ancestors violation dissappeared and the video played successfully. I then changed the url to '**https://www.ifThisIsEmptyThenVideoWillNotPlay.com**' and it still worked, so I guess it just has to be a url. I'm not sure if this will help, but I felt I had to put it somewhere as it seemed obscure to me...